# Passing email address from params to a model method in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

In the following code I get "wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)" for the following line
user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
if params[:email] contains @ character. Without the @ character everything works fine, I don't have a single idea how to solve it.

I tried to give an email as string like user = User.authenticate("test@test.com", params[:password]) and I don't get the error.

Could anyone help with it?

My code:

Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController  
  def new  
  end  

  def create  
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])  
    if user  
      session[:user_id] = user.id  
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"  
    else  
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"  
      render "new"  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessor :password  
  before_save :encrypt_password  

  validates_confirmation_of :password  
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create  
  validates_presence_of :email  
  validates_uniqueness_of :email  

  def encrypt_password  
    if password.present?  
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt  
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)  
    end  
  end  

  def self.authenticate(email, password)  
    user = find_by_email(email)  
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret ↵  
      (password, user.password_salt)  
       user  
    else  
       nil  
    end  
  end
```

end

Comment: what is the type of your email field?

Comment: can you add paste your stack trace in a gist?  even if `params[:email]` and `params[:password]` are nil, you shouldn't be getting that error because you're still passing 2 parameters to `#authenticate`

Comment: the mail field is created by <%= f.text :email %>

Comment: my application trace: https://gist.github.com/npometko/4731482
params[:email] and params[:password] are not nil, anyway if they were I would still passing 2 arguments..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
User.authenticate(params[:email].to_s, params[:password])
```

This is because your email type is string and you are passing it a hash in the method.

Comment: According to gist, the error is in session controller line number 10, which is `redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"`. Try only 'redirect_to root_url'

Comment: Does not change anything, even if I comment the whole redirect line

Comment: I don't believe it...

I started to check each line in the model method by commenting out everything and checking each line. I uncommented the if line without else only with true branch if.... user end. Ok, worked. Then I typed again the else brach. Guess what? Now it's working with the very same code I had there earlier, just retyped.

How could this happen?!